# Why does the applicationWillResignActive method not work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

In my GameScene.m I have a method called *wentToBackGround*. This method is called by *applicationWillResignActive* in AppDelegate:

```
GameScene *gameScene = [[GameScene alloc]init];
[gameScene wentToBackground];
```

In wentToBackGround I move my player sprite (just to test if it works) like so:

```
-(void)wentToBackground {
  NSLog(@"BG");
  self.player.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 1000);
}
```

The *NSLog* works, however the players position remains the same. Is this due to the fact that SpriteKit automatically pauses everything once it enters the BG. How do I work around this. I eventually want there to be a pause menu that opens as soon as the user leaves the app. **How do I do this properly?**

I think it also might not work, because I made a new instance of the *GameScene*. How do I use the old instance? (the old instance was created in another scene, the *TitleScene*)

Comment: "I eventually want there to be a pause menu that opens as soon as the user leaves the app" But this may be useless because by the time you learn the user is leaving the app the user will have left the app.

Comment: Yes but when he/she comes back the pause menu is automatically opened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it also might not work, because I made a new instance of the GameScene

Correct, you got it! Well done. Keep in mind (and I think you are now grasping this) that a class is just a template. The objects in your app are instances, and you can make many instances of one class. So when you say

```
[[GameScene alloc]init]
```

you are making a *new* instance. That's legal but pointless; sending it the `wentToBackground` message does nothing of any use, because it isn't in your interface. The GameScene instance you want to talk to, the one in your interface, is elsewhere.

Getting a reference to a particular existing instance can be tricky. You sometimes have to arrange things in advance to make it possible. However, I think you can avoid the whole problem here. UIApplication has not only an app delegate method but also a *notification* for letting you know that you will resign active. So just have the GameScene register for that notification, and now you don't have to involve the app delegate at all.

Here's the documentation on that notification:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification

Any object can register for a notification, so this is a way to establish that your GameScene wants to be informed of deactivation.

Comment: And see my discussion here on how to register for and receive notifications: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html#_notifications

Comment: Okay, I now have it installed and it is working(I changed it to willEnterForeground), however the method gets called twice for some reason.

Comment: Notifications are unfortunately tricky. You may be registering twice. If you do that, you'll be notified twice. You need to guard against letting that happen...

Comment: Or in AppDelegate will resign active do `[((GameScene*)((SKView*)(_window.rootViewController.view)).scene) wentToBackground];`. Remember to #import SpriteKit in the .h and GameScene.h in the .m file